# How to insert only date part in to datetime colomn in sql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to insert auto generated date in to my sql table. But it genarating time also when using both of dateime and timestamp data types. But i need to genarate  only the date part . How can i do that

Comment: Show the exact SQL you're using please, and any relevant data, and what results you get. In theory if you just inserted a date string without any time, you'd still get a datetime in the table but the time would be midnight (00:00:00) so it wouldn't matter. If you're inserting from another application using a built-in date/time type in that programming language then you might have to truncate/reset the time component before you insert, if it's not already done. See also [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

[`CURDATE()` returns the present date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) just as `NOW()` returns the current date/time in MySQL.

And, [`DATE(any_datetime_or_timestamp)` retrieves just the date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) given any `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` value.

So you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO tbl (something, day) VALUES ('something', CURDATE())
```

to get a row with the current date, without time.

MySQL lets you [declare columns something like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to generate timestamps automatically. For DATETIME you need version 8+.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

These do not allow you to insert only the date, without time, automatically.  But when you query the table you can do

```
SELECT DATE(ts) tsdate, DATE(dt) dtdate
```

to get back only the date part.

Or, with recent versions, you can use a so-called [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) in the table if you just want the date. Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    tsdate DATE AS DATE(ts)
);
```

This can come in handy if you need an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) on that date-only column.